# Entities implementing interfaces

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I'm new to JPA and Hiberante therefore my question may sound a bit dumbly.

I've heard that using the annotation [MappedSuperclass](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/MappedSuperclass.html) is a bad practice because it generates a horrible DDL schema of the actual Data. Therefore I'm trying to avoid using it in real code as much as it may be possible. But now I'd like to make an entity, e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class UnsubscribedPlayer implements SimpleId{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name= "email")
    private String email;

    //Get, Set

}
```

implementing interface:

```
public interface SimpleId{
    public int getId();
}
```

Is common in hibernate and JPA to make entities imlementing interfaces or there're some limitations?

Comment: No there is no limitations. @MAppedSupperClass is used especially in the case of abstract classes (not concrete classes) where a sub-class must inherit properties, associations and methods.

Comment: This can help : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: If the super class is a concrete one, you'll need an inheritance strategy using @Inheritance.

Comment: Could you add the reference, for the _horrible DDL_ statement? As long as you only define the ID in the `MappedSuperclass` there is no difference to your approach in the generated DDL.